# Crystalline exact sequence in Galois cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $1\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow 1$ be a short exact sequence of (non-abelian) algebraic group schemes over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ equipped with a $G$ action (the maps are $G$-equivariant).

It is well known that there exists a long exact sequence in Galois cohomology:

$0\longrightarrow A^G\longrightarrow B^G\longrightarrow C^G\longrightarrow H^1(G,A)\longrightarrow H^1(G,B)\longrightarrow H^1(G,C).$

I am interested in knowing whether there is a similar exact sequence in Crystalline Galois cohomology, i.e. if I add the crystalline restriction, I still have an exact sequence:

$0\longrightarrow A^G\longrightarrow B^G\longrightarrow C^G\longrightarrow H^1_f(G,A)\longrightarrow H^1_f(G,B)\longrightarrow H^1_f(G,C).$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess $G$ should be the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It would be good to add (a reference to) the definition of $H^1_f$ in the non-abelian case.

Comment: Uhhh $A^G$ doesn't make sense; do you mean $A(\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p})^G$?

Comment: Why should it not make sense? I said that these groups come equipped with a (non-trivial) $G$-action. The case I care about is when this is a conjugation action, so, for example, $1\in A$ is always $G$-fixed.

Comment: Hmm, ok. You said they were group schemes. Then I'm confused about the meaning of $H^1_f(G,A)$ in this particular setup. Can you define it precisely for us?

Comment: I could, but if I'm honest I don't know how to prove this statement even in the case when $A,B,C$ are replaced with arbitrary (or crystalline) representations. Should that be obvious?

Comment: If $A, B, C$ are crystalline representations, your statement is true for highly nontrivial reasons. I'm quite certain it fails in general. (Sorry, I'm on my phone in the subway, can't look up references.)

Comment: Very very curious to see an argument, whether from a reference or an answer.